# Disable Auto login on PayPal checkout

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, checkout, autologin

Hello here is my problem. On my woocommerce shop i use paypal gateway. When I try to pay first I see page when i can choise how to pay via account or card. After login to account I can`t change it. If i return to site and try to pay again I don`t see choise, PayPal autologins me and on that page I can change account or pay via another card. This is problem for my site because stupid users don`t know how to log out and pay again. P.S. In api request 'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Billing' or 'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Login' has no effect.

Comment: There should just be a small link that says "Change Payment Method".  Can you provide a screenshot of the PayPal screens you're seeing?

Comment: I see this screeen [link](http://i.piccy.info/i9/c30f1412dc1b6254f345667c0ea097e7/1472128750/52958/1063794/juli_screen.png)

Comment: The option to change payment method would be after you've signed in to your account.